# Extending the Safari Address Bar When Many Extensions Installed?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

I have a number of extensions installed that have shrunk my address bar down to a very undesirable size for input and reviewing URLs.  Is there a way to extend the address bar such that extension buttons will function more like Chrome or Firefox in Safari?

*NOTE: I am not looking to entirely remove the extension buttons, but rather to hide them into an unfoldable / expandable menu similar to how Chrome and Firefox do it when you horizontally resize the address bar (eg, it hides the right-most icons down into a drop-down accessible menu).

Answer (score 1):

Have you right-clicked the toolbar, gone to Customize Toolbar, and moved some items off of it?

Comment: This is more of a comment, as an answer should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that.  That does indeed get rid of the extension from the toolbar, but I'd like to have access to all of the functions readily via a dropdown method like unto Chrome or Firefox.  In other words, I was hoping that there may be an extension or such that will allow the address bar to be expanded horizontally while hiding the rightmost extension buttons at a given point down into an expandable menu a la that which is noted above.